# Are there free modules over Non-Principal Ideal Domains

Tags: abstract-algebra

Can you give some examples for free Modules over Non-PIDS (but Ring is commutative with 1)?

Comment: What about $R^n$? See [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FreeModule.html): "The free module of rank $n$ over a nonzero unit ring R, usually denoted $R^n$..."

Answer (score 2):

For any ring $R$ and any set $X$, there is a free module over $R$ on generators $X$, and any such module is isomorphic to $\bigoplus_{x\in X} R$. When $X$ is finite of size $n$, the statement simplifies to: a free module over $R$ on $n$ generators is isomorphic to $R^n$.

Being a PID has nothing to do with it!